# Two questions related to Ruby threads

Tags: ruby, inheritance, multithreading

First one:

- how can I create a Thread that doesn't start right away.If I use `initialize` without a block an exception gets raised.
- how can I subclass Thread, so that I may add some custom attributes, but keep the same functionality as the base Thread class? I'd also like to not have to use the `initialize(&block)` method for this.

To better illustrate this:

For the first question:

```
x = Thread.new
x.run = {
  # this should happen inside the thread
}
x.start # i want to manually start the thread
```

For the second:

```
x = MyThread.new
x.my_attribute = some_value
x.run = {
  # this should happen when the thread runs
}
x.start
```

I'm looking for something similar to this. Hope you can help.

Comment: Why can't you "just" replace `x.start` with `x = Thread.new {etc}`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Question 1**

Examining the MRI 1.8.7 source revealed no obvious way to start a thread in the "stopped" state.

What you can do is to have the thread block on a locked mutex, then unlock the mutex when you want the thread to go.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

go = Mutex.new
go.lock
t = Thread.new do
  puts "Thread waiting to go"
  go.lock
  puts "Thread going"
end
puts "Telling the thread to go"
go.unlock
puts "Waiting for the thread to complete"
t.join

# => Thread waiting to go
# => Telling the thread to go
# => Thread going
# => Waiting for the thread to complete
```

**Question 2 (Sort Of)**

Did you know you can pass arguments to your thread?  Anything passed to Thread.new gets passed through as block arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

t = Thread.new(1, 2, 3) do |a, b, c|
  puts "Thread arguments: #{[a, b, c].inspect}"
  # => Thread arguments: [1, 2, 3]
end
```

There are also "thread local variables," a per-thread key/value store.  Use `Thread#[]=` to set values, and `Thread#[]` to get them back.  You can use string or symbols as keys.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

go = Mutex.new
go.lock
t = Thread.new(1, 2, 3) do |a, b, c|
  go.lock
  p Thread.current[:foo]    # => "Foo!"
end  
t[:foo] = "Foo!"
go.unlock
t.join
```

**Question 2, Really**

You can do what you want to do.  It's a lot of work, especially when the usual way of handling threads is so simple.  You'll have to weigh the plusses and minuses:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

require 'forwardable'

class MyThread

  extend Forwardable

  def_delegator :@thread, :join
  def_delegator :@thread, :[]=
  def_delegator :@thread, :[]

  def initialize
    @go = Mutex.new
    @go.lock
    @thread = Thread.new do
      @go.lock
      @stufftodo.call
    end
  end

  def run(&block)
    @stufftodo = block
    @go.unlock
    @thread.join
  end

end

t = MyThread.new
t[:foo] = "Foo!"
t.run do
  puts Thread.current[:foo]
end
t.join

# => "Foo!"
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this detailed answer. I went with thread variables, using the `Thread.current` method. Your answer was very interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
stuff_to_do = lambda do 
   # this happens in the thread
end

x = Thread.new( &stuff_to_do )
```

Comment: What does the ampersand do?  The code breaks without it, but I want to understand the syntax.

Comment: @DanJameson You use the ampersand to pass a proc as a block to a function without using the block syntax. Here's an example, the following snippets are equivalent: `foo { puts "This is the block syntax" }` and `my_proc = lambda { puts "Passing a proc rather than using the block syntax" }; foo(&my_proc)`

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the [example from Ruby-Doc 1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Thread.html#method-i-wakeup) because it contains a race condition. See [Ruby 2 example](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Thread.html#method-i-wakeup), or something like the following:

I tested this in Ruby 2.0 and Ruby 1.8.7, and I found that calling `#wakeup` was not enough in 1.8.7' I had to call `#run`.  The following seems to work in both:

```
t = Thread.new { Thread.stop; puts "HELLO" }
until t.stop?; end  # ensure thread has actually stopped before we tell it to resume
t.run
```

Comment: This has a race condition. If the t.run happens before the Thread.stop then the thread will never go past that.

Comment: Chris is right. I actually just ran into this condition. I've updated the post with a busy-wait to avoid the race.